# Adding additional loss with constant zero output changes model convergence

Tags: loss-function, machine-translation, returnn

I have setup a Returnn Transformer Model for NMT, which I want to train with an additional loss for every encoder/decoder attention head `h` on every decoder layer `l` (in addition to the vanilla Cross Entropy loss), i.e.:

```
loss = CrossEntropyLoss + sum_{Layer l=1,...,6} sum_{Head h=1,...,8} (lambda * AttentionLoss(l, h))
```

for some scalar `lambda`. I implemented the attention loss itself as a `eval`-Layer, using the `loss=as_is` option, that returns a single number for each batch (that is the value of `lambda * AttentionLoss(l, h)`.

As a test, I also implemented a version where I have one loss for each layer `l`, equivalent to `lambda * sum_{Head h=1,...,8} AttentionLoss(l, h)` to reduce the number of losses as I noticed a decrease in performance and as log files were getting very large as Returnn prints every loss for each batch.

However, I got very different results for both implementations: A model trained with one loss per layer AND head performs consistently better. I tried this with multiple training runs.

To investigate this, I tried a training run where I set the parameter `lambda=0.0`, i.e. effectively disabled the attention loss. And even here, in comparison to the baseline without any additional losses, a model trained with these additional 6 losses all outputting a constant 0 performs noticably worse, see this table:

```
+--------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+
|                                            |   Dev Set   |   Test Set  |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
|                                            | BLEU |  TER | BLEU |  TER |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| Only Cross Entropy Loss                    | 35.7 | 51.4 | 34.2 | 53.5 |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| + One loss per layer and head (lambda 0)   | 35.5 | 51.5 | 33.9 | 53.7 |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| + One loss per layer (lambda 0)            | 35.4 | 51.8 | 33.5 | 54.2 |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
| + Simplified One loss per layer (lambda 0) | 35.1 | 52.0 | 33.5 | 54.3 |
+--------------------------------------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Here, the "simplified" version is implemented exactly like this:

```
'dec_01_weight_loss': {
   'class': 'eval', 'eval': '0.0 * tf.reduce_sum(source(0, auto_convert=False))',
   'from': ['dec_01_att_weights'], 'loss': 'as_is',
   'out_type': {   'batch_dim_axis': None, 'dim': None, 'dtype': 'float32', 'feature_dim_axis': None,
                   'shape': (), 'time_dim_axis': None}}
```

while the actual loss I use is a bit more complicated, I [uploaded my full config files here.](https://gist.github.com/Zettelkasten/3771a29b5d674f8e462f2fd73007d588) (Here the loss layer is called `dec_01_att_weight_variance` etc.)

And all `lambda=0.0` implementions mentioned above output the value `0.0` for all additional losses in every training step:

```
train epoch 1, step 0, cost:output/dec_01_weight_loss 0.0, cost:output/dec_02_weight_loss 0.0, cost:output/dec_03_weight_loss 0.0, [....], cost:output/output_prob 8.541749455164052, error:decision 0.0, error:output/output_prob 0.9999999680730979, loss 8.5417 49, max_mem_usage:GPU:0 1.2GB, mem_usage:GPU:0 1.2GB, 3.999 sec/step, elapsed 0:00:38, exp. remaining 1:30:00, complete 0.71%
```

What is going on here? Is there any explanation why the models behave differently, why does an additional loss with a constant value `0.0` change the model behavior?

I am using TF 1.15.0 (v1.15.0-0-g590d6eef7e), Returnn 20200613.152716--git-23332ca, using Python 3.8.0 with CUDA 10.1.

---

**Followup Update**: I tested the same config using pre-training, where I would disable my loss completely for the first `n-1` (here e.g. `n=50`) checkpoints using the following code:

```
def custom_construction_algo(idx, net_dict):
    if idx == 0:
        for lay in range(1, 7):
             del net_dict["output"]["unit"]["dec_%02i_att_loss" % lay]
        return net_dict
    else:
        return None
pretrain = {"repetitions": 49, "construction_algo": custom_construction_algo}
```

In the log file, for the first `n-1` checkpoints I (correctly) only see the CE loss being reported.

Here I am showing my Dev BLEU at the last checkpoint trained without the additional loss (i.e. `n-1`, here `49`), each experiment run multiple times:

- Baseline (no additional loss): 31.8, 31.7, 31.7 BLEU
- One loss per layer disabled with pretraining: 29.2, 29.0, 28.5 BLEU
- One loss per layer with `lambda=0.0` (as in original question): 28.8, 28.7 BLEU
- One loss per layer AND head with `lambda=0.0` (as in original question): 31.8 BLEU

From my understanding, the TF graph for pre-training config and the baseline should be identical up to checkpoint `n=50`. Yet, they perform very differently. What is going on?

The full config I used for this kind of pre-training can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Zettelkasten/26d1635dfbebea554c4dab5e750c7fe3). The heads of the corresponding log files are found [here](https://gist.github.com/Zettelkasten/07d99000f552fbb75c2d0715bbafaca0).
I am using NewbobMultiEpoch with Adam:

```
learning rate control: NewbobMultiEpoch(num_epochs=9, update_interval=1, relative_error_threshold=0, learning_rate_decay_factor=0.7, learning_rate_growth_factor=1.0), epoch data: , error key: None
Create optimizer <class 'tensorflow.python.training.adam.AdamOptimizer'> with options {'beta1': 0.9, 'beta2': 0.999, 'epsilon': 1e-08, 'learning_rate': <tf.Variable 'learning_rate:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>}.
```

For all reported experiments, the learning rate does not decrease until checkpoints larger than 100, staying constant at initial `10^-4`.

**EDIT:** *I did a mistake and accidentally **used a different Returnn version across my experiments**. The Returnn I used for my experiments with additional losses seems to have contained some local changes I made. When rerunning a baseline with the new version, it performed significantly worse - very similar to the other BLEU values documented here.* A subtle bug in one of my Returnn versions - thats all that was to this issue.

Comment: Can you upload both config variants to a GitHub Gist or so? What TF version do you use? Can you also try with latest TF version (2.3.0)?

Comment: @Albert I updated my question accordingly. I can try the same experiment with TF 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aware that the training is non-deterministic anyway, right? Did you try to rerun each case a couple of times? Also the baseline? Maybe the baseline itself is an outlier.

Also, changing the computation graph, even if this will be a no-op, can also have an effect. Unfortunately it can be sensitive.

You might want to try setting `deterministic_train = True` in your config. This might make it a bit more deterministic. Maybe you get the same result then in each of your cases. This might make it a bit slower, though.

The order of parameter initialization might be different as well. The order depends on the order of when the layers are created. Maybe compare that in the log. It is always the same random initializer, but would use a different seed offset then, so you would get another initialization.
You could play around by explicitly setting `random_seed` in the config, and see how much variance you get by that. Maybe all these values are within this range.

For a more in-depth debugging, you could really compare directly the computation graph (in TensorBoard). Maybe there is a difference which you did not notice. Also, maybe make a diff on the log output during net construction, for the case pretrain vs baseline. There should be no diff.

(As this is maybe a mistake, for now only as a side comment: Of course, different RETURNN versions might have some different behavior. So this should be the same.)

Another note: You do not need this `tf.reduce_sum` in your loss. Actually that might not be such a good idea. Now it will forget about number of frames, and number of seqs. If you just do not use `tf.reduce_sum`, it should also work, but now you get the correct normalization.

Another note: Instead of your `lambda`, you can also use `loss_scale`, which is simpler, and you get the original value in the log.

So basically, you could write it this way:

```
'dec_01_weight_loss': {
   'class': 'copy', 'from': 'dec_01_att_weights',
   'loss': 'as_is', 'loss_scale': ...}
```

This should be (mostly) equivalent. Actually it should be more correct, as it will not take the masked frames into account (those behind seq end).

Note that using `pretrain` (by default) will keep the learning rate fixed. This might be a difference in your experiments. (But simply check your log / learning rate data file for this.)
Btw, if this is the case, it looks like the fixed learning rate (probably higher learning rate) seems to perform better, right? So maybe you even want to do that by default?

Also check your log for "reinit because network description differs". This should have no big effect, but who knows. This will also reset the current state of the optimizer (momentum or so; I guess you use Adam?). But even with pretrain, I think you will not have this, as you always keep the network the same.

Actually, speaking of learning rate: How did you configure the learning rate scheduling? It has a somewhat "clever" logic to determine which score to look at (used for the threshold). If it looks at some of your custom losses, the behavior will be different. Esp if you do not use `loss_scale` as I explained, this will also play a role.
You can configure it explicitly via `learning_rate_control_error_measure`.

---

As a small demonstration, how you still get some non-zero gradient, even for `0.0 * loss`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import better_exchook


def main():
  max_seq_len = 15
  seq_len = 10

  logits = tf.zeros([max_seq_len])
  mask = tf.less(tf.range(max_seq_len), seq_len)
  logits_masked = tf.where(mask, logits, float("-inf"))
  ce = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(mask, tf.nn.softmax(logits_masked) * tf.nn.log_softmax(logits_masked), 0.0))
  loss = 0.0 * ce

  d_logits, = tf.gradients(loss, [logits])

  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
    print(session.run((ce, loss, d_logits)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  better_exchook.install()
  tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
  main()
```

This will output:
`(2.3025851, 0.0, array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32))`

This gets `nan`, but I think you might also be able to construct cases where you get some non-inf/non-nan/non-zero value.

If you want to dump gradients in your eval layer, or in general in TF code, in a very simple way, you can do this:

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops


@ops.RegisterGradient("IdentityWithPrint")
def _identity_with_print(op, grad):
  with tf.control_dependencies([tf.print([op.name, "grad:", grad])]):
    return [tf.identity(grad)]


def debug_grad(x):
  """
  :param tf.Tensor x:
  :return: x, but gradient will be printed
  :rtype: tf.Tensor
  """
  g = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
  with g.gradient_override_map({"Identity": "IdentityWithPrint"}):
    return tf.identity(x, name=x.name.split("/")[-1].replace(":", "_"))
```

And then you just write (at the beginning of your eval layer):
`x = debug_grad(source(0, auto_convert=False))`
Or sth like that.
Maybe extend the `tf.print(...)`, e.g. with `summarize=-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You might be right - maybe this just happened by random chance after all - even though I would not expect such a large difference. I will run more trainings to be sure.
My actual formula for calculating the loss is a bit more complicated, essentially this is the variance of the weights over the source-time-axis. I could not figure out how to specify the `eval`-layer's `out_type` to contain only one of the input's time axes.
I am however handling padding in the eval layer explicitly - but this should not make any difference for lambda=0.0 anyway?

Comment: I admit that my solution with the long `eval`-string is very ugly/bad - I should probably change it to use a separate layer for each individual operation (then, Returnn would also automatically handle padding when I e.g. reduce over a time axis). For `lambda=0.0` however, should this change much?

Comment: Even adding `tf.no_op` or `+ 0.0` or `* 1.0` to a graph could change the behavior because of timings, and maybe some optimizations are not triggered then or whatever. I agree, this is maybe not likely, but I think this is possible. Btw, for `0 * x`, there can be an effect for the gradient. For the padding, you will get some infs there (for the grad), so `0 * inf` might cancel somehow. So there might be some error signal after all. Maybe debug the grad you get after your loss, even with `lambda=0.0`.

Comment: Thanks for posting the `debug_grad` function!. I tried it, and can now verify that (at least for the first few training steps) when `lambda=0.0`, the gradients are also `0` for the all entries of `source(0)` of my eval-loss (including padding). For `lambda>0.0`, I see that the gradient of all padded entries is also zero (no NaNs or anything).

Comment: I reran my experiments multiple times and also added a follow up to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not know that! However, all the experiments I mentioned only start to decrease my learning rate longer after checkpoint 100, staying constant at my initial set `10^-4`. Is there anything else that is different?

Comment: Urghs, also sorry, I mixed up the result lines for my baseline and the experiment with pretraining. The pre-train experiment performs worse (similar to the `lambda=0.0`-loss) - I fixed it this in my question and also added my learning rate control + optimizer.
I am getting `reinit because network description differs.`, but only at checkpoint `n=50`.

Comment: I uploaded my log files, see my original question. I am not using `random_seed` or `deterministic_train` currently. However, doesn't Returnn set the seed equally if both configs do not specify `random_seed` (in `TFEngine.py` there is `tf_random_seed = 42`, `net_random_seed = epoch`)? Note that for the Baseline Ckp. 49 Results I reported, two of those were generated by specifying a conrete `random_seed` - I do not think the seed has such large influence.
If I didn't miss anything, both Returnn logs also seem equal - same order and same layers, from what I see mostly exactly identical output.

Comment: I will also try with `deterministic_train` now and look into comparing the TF graphs. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Yes, RETURNN sets the random seed. But I ask you to start multiple experiments each with a different random seed. To get an idea how much variance that will produce.

Comment: GitHub appears to truncate the pre-trained log file when not viewing the raw version, see here for the version I uploaded: https://gist.github.com/Zettelkasten/07d99000f552fbb75c2d0715bbafaca0/raw/acae547fb266e8cf3aff184f6e57671e7c51134e/pretraining_each_layer.log.head
Let me know if you need further logs.
Yes, all trainings have been run on 1080 only. For inference, I also use other GPUs - however that should not make big difference there, right?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I noticed that this is not the same RETURNN version (20200613.152716--git-23332ca vs 20200316.120902--git-032125f). Do you have that mixed up? That would explain the difference. If the older version seems to be consistently better, it would be very nice if you could do some bisect search to identify the commit when it got worse. For inference, I think the GPU (and RETURNN version) does not matter. (I cleaned up my comments here a bit.)

Comment: Oh no, I guess I really mixed that up! Thanks a lot finding for that out!!! I will try the pre-training experiment with the old version I used in the baseline, as well as with the latest version from GitHub. The version I used also had some (minor?) local changes, that might have turned out to not be as minor after all ...